# Can I use a format.ps1xml file to format a class created in PowerShell and if so, how?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I've created a class:

```
Class Group {
    [Guid]$Id
    [String]$DisplayName
    [String[]]$Schemas
}
```

and a Test.format.ps1xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Configuration>

  <SelectionSets>
  </SelectionSets>

  <Controls>
  </Controls>

  <ViewDefinitions>

    <View>
      <Name>Group</Name>

      <ViewSelectedBy>
        <TypeName>Group</TypeName>
      </ViewSelectedBy>

      <ListControl>
        <ListEntries>
          <ListEntry>
            <ListItems>
              <ListItem>
                <PropertyName>Id</PropertyName>
              </ListItem>
              <ListItem>
                <PropertyName>DisplayName</PropertyName>
              </ListItem>
            </ListItems>
          </ListEntry>
        </ListEntries>
      </ListControl>
    </View>

  </ViewDefinitions>
</Configuration>
```

I add the format to the current PowerShell instance:

```
Update-formatdata –prependpath "C:\Work\Test.format.ps1xml"
```

But, when I create an instance of Group the format doesn't get applied and I see all of the members of the class.

E.g.

```
$group = New-Object Group
$group.Id = [Guid]::NewGuid()
$group.DisplayName = 'Name'
$group.Schemas = @('schema1', 'schema2')
$group
```

generates:

```
PS C:\Work> $group

Id          : e2b6ccff-e72d-4494-8242-975618889c9c
DisplayName : Name
Schemas     : {schema1, schema2}
```

I'd have expected not to see the Schemas line.

Comment: 1) Make sure you use clean PowerShell session for test (`powershell -noprofile`). 2) Show `$group.PSTypeNames`. 3) Construct [mcve] (your code work fine for me).

Comment: You're right.  That's what I'd tried to do because this was part of a PowerShell module which wasn't behaving but I'd failed to save the format file after removing the line for the Schemas member.  Doh!  Thanks for making me revisit it. +1 for that.

Answer (score 0):

I am suspecting schema definition is not proper,can you check with this ps1xml:

```
<Configuration>
  <ViewDefinitions>
    <View>
      <Name>Group</Name>
      <ViewSelectedBy>
        <TypeName>Group</TypeName>
      </ViewSelectedBy>
      <TableControl>
        <TableHeaders>
          <TableColumnHeader>
            <Width>33</Width>
          </TableColumnHeader>
          <TableColumnHeader>
            <Width>12</Width>
            <Alignment>Center</Alignment>
          </TableColumnHeader>      
        </TableHeaders>
        <TableRowEntries>
          <TableRowEntry>
            <TableColumnItems>
              <TableColumnItem>
                <PropertyName>displayname</PropertyName>
              </TableColumnItem>
              <TableColumnItem>
                <PropertyName>id</PropertyName>
              </TableColumnItem>
            </TableColumnItems>
          </TableRowEntry>
        </TableRowEntries>
      </TableControl>
    </View>
  </ViewDefinitions>
</Configuration>
```